# JAXB not detecting elements

Tags: java, xml, youtube, jaxb, rss

I am trying to utilize JAXB to convert xml elements gained from a youtube rss feed into objects. I seem to be following the structure of most examples I have seen, but still cannot get it to work as it always seem the list within feed is empty at all times. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here are my classes for reference:

feed class:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.*;

@XmlRootElement(
    name = "feed",
    namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    )
    @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class feed {

    @XmlElement(name = "entry")
    private List<entry> entries;
    public List<entry> getEntry() {
        return this.entries;
    }
    public void setEntry(List<entry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
}
```

Entry class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class entry {
private String title, name, id, published;


public void settitle(String title){this.title = title;}
public String gettitle(){return title;}

public void setname(String name){this.name = name;};
public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public void setid(String id){this.id = id;}
public String getid() {
    return id;
}

public void setpublished(String published){this.published = published;}
public String getpublished() {return published;}


public void PrintVideoInfo(){
    System.out.println(gettitle());
    System.out.println(getname());
    System.out.println(getid());
    System.out.println(getpublished());
    System.out.println("-----------");
}
}
```

unmarshalling class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class XMLtoObject {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        File file = new File("videos.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(feed.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        feed que= (feed) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        for(entry ent:que.getEntry())
            ent.PrintVideoInfo();

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCBcRF18a7Qf58cCRy5xuWwQ this is the xml being used. It is saved as videos.xml and the file path is correct, just not fully included for privacy in the above snippet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to put a break point in the setter. If it breaks  checks the contents

Comment: @efekctive after testing with a breakpoint, it enters the feed class and hits the @xmlelement(name = "entry") line, but then it does not enter the entry class at all. Is it because i'm only trying to account for specific information from the XML file rather than all of it?

Comment: In other words: the parameter entries in "setEntry(List<entry> entries)" is null or empty?

Comment: Entry class has not annotations other than root element. It needs something like "@XmlElement(name = "entry")" If this works I will post it as an answer

Comment: Are you saying to put an @XmlElement(name = variable) for every variable within the Entry class? the parameter entries may be null, i am not entirely sure if anything is passing a list to it during the unmarshalling process.

Comment: Ok. Do me a favor place a breakpoint in the line "this.entries = entries;" and run the app using the debugger. If execution stops there, check the value of the parameter. Tell me if it is null or empty

Comment: @efekctive Placed a breakpoint and ran, the code seems to never approach that line at all.

Comment: But the list is EMPTY as you wrote in the OP?

Comment: If the list is empty it means that jaxb could not deserialize any entries. I think it has to do with the fact that the Entry class has no annotations to process

Comment: @efekctive So would that be because of incorrect modeling of the class? My fields definitely matched the tags within every entry element in that youtube XML i provided

Comment: Just compare the annotations in Feed and Entry classes. As the xml feed is processed, jaxb needs to know where to set the xml values. It looks at Entry. It just finds a root element that basically maps root to class name. After that any other xml value has no destination.

Comment: @efekctive So essentially i need to use xmlelement annotations behind entry's variables so it knows where to map the xml values? I had just attempted that but it seems still no dice.

Comment: Deleting my answer since the problem is not happening from this end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please, make your class names follow Pascal notation - it's way easier to read and understand, especially when there's a lot of code. Probably, you should work on your code style more.
2. Your `feed` class is annotated correctly, but in order for JAXB to unmarshal XML into entries `entry` class should also be annotated properly. Also note, that your field names do not match tag names in the xml file provided (`<name>` is not directly accessible within `<feed>`). 
   So, add annotations and classes to match xml file structure.

**UPDATE 1**

I realized I didn't quite understand xml documents, so I made a little investigation.

If you're completely familiar with xml namespaces, then you can skip this part to Serialization section. Otherwise, read on.

**Namespace** is a mechanism of dividing xml nodes into non-intersecting sets. Imagine having an `<address>` tag in your xml, where the tag is defined many times. It could either refer to a web address or a street address, for example, and thus have completely different meaning depending on context. To avoid confusion, you add a namespace prefix like that: `<web:address>` `<street:address>` to separate them and group other elements referring to the same namespace. You define them earlier in some root tag:

```
<root xmlns:web="Web"> 
    <web:address> ... </web:address>
</root>
```

Also, there's a special namespace - *default namespace* - which is defined like this: `<feed xmlns="Name">`. Having a default namespace allows you to omit writing namespace prefix every time you define an xml element.

Let's clear this up with your xml example: it states three namespaces for `<feed>` element (yt, media, and the **default** namespace)

```
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" 
      xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

That means **every** element inside `<feed>` is kind of implicitly prefixed with the default namespace.

[Intro to XML namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

[Atom namespace explained](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/atom.html)

**Serialization**

I downloaded the xml file you provided and did some tests. It turned out, that JAXB just "didn't see" the entity tags, since they are hidden behind the default namspace, and we never said to JAXB there is a namespace at all, except for the `<feed>` element.

So, the solution is to annotate the elements you want to deserialize with a namespace, so that JAXB could understand that.

**UPDATE 2**

It looked as if the solution provided above was too messy: having to annotate every other element with a namespace is truly a violation of DRY principle. Fortunately, there is a solution to add a default namespace in just one line.

Create a file called *package-info.java* and add the following in it and replace `package` with yours:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

All it does is defines an xml schema for the document we want to parse. You can now remove all `namespace = "..."` lines and pretty up the code
If you're not familiar with xml schemas, check it out as it's a great way to keep control of xml documents structure.

The code after update 2:

Feed class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "feed")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class Feed {

    @XmlElement(name = "entry")
    private List<Entry> entries;

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return this.entries;
    }

}
```

Entry class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.Date;

@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {

    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "published")
    private Date datePublished;

    @XmlElement(name = "author")
    private Author author;

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Id: %s, Title: %s, Author: %s, Published: %s",
               id,
               title,
               author.toString(),
               datePublished.toString());
        }

}
```

Author class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "author")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Author {

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    private String url;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

Main

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Feed feed = (Feed) JAXBContext
                .newInstance(Feed.class)
                .createUnmarshaller()
                .unmarshal(new File("youtube_feed.xml"));

        for (Entry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
            System.out.println(entry.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

**Reading comprehension**

[JAXB and XML namespaces](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html)

[Oracle JAXB annotations reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/customize.html)

Comment: I apologize, my code actually looks perfectly organized on intelliJ, it just seemed to lose its indentation when i put it into here! the first few tags actually are not for an entry but moreso for the channel itself.

Comment: Also would the xml not having only entry's matter? This is an xml file i took from a youtube channel that I would have to be able to extract data out of without modifying the file. I attempted to add xmlelement notations to the rest of the elements in the entry class, but it seems to still be unable to create them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extremely detailed solution! I will read up on it in the morning and test it for myself!:)

Comment: Hi @GoodMove, I tried to copy and paste all these classes myself and fixed the filepath to check if it works, but i seem to be having issues with the namespace. I think I am confused with what you did on Update 2. Did you just create an entire new java file with just that small code snippet within it, in that order? Because it seems to be telling me this is not possible, and even after moving the imports and packages it is telling me "Annotations are not allowed here"

Comment: @DevinAmatya, yes, just create a java file with named `package-info.java`, paste the code there and update path to your package

Comment: Hm would you happen to have the project on you? I tried to do it but it consistently tells me that i can't apply the annotation in package-info cause there's nothing to annotate.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work! IntelliJ was just being rather weird and not realizing i placed my package name correctly. If possible, is there any explanation about how to create a program to unmarshal an xml file depending on the type the xml is?(such as one from youtube, and a different one from an external site). if you could contact me by email about this matter this would help GRANDLY. :)

Comment: @DevinAmatya if you want to unmarshal two completely unrelated xml documents, you'll have to have two sets of classes that represent each document model. That said, generalizing this algorithm is an overkill, I suppose, and it's better to create two separate programs. Same applies to >2 case.

Comment: Ah okay i understand. Using these documents I was able to extract all the information I need!:) Is there a way of doing this through a get request, however? I've heard of something called JAX-RS, but I am unsure if it is what I want. I specifically wanted to obtain the xml from the url i posted above through a get request and unmarshal it that way.

Comment: @DevinAmatya, JAXB is just a serialization tool. It doesn't care about the source of your document. Just read about networking tools in Java and then combine the two. Also, don't hesitate to refer to [Orace Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/). All standard java tools are described there in details.

Comment: Ah okay I'll look into it. My final question is, what do i do when there is no default namespace provided? https://web.stagram.com/rss/n/instagram it has several namespaces but none are in just a plain xmlns. Iam trying to get the data in items and it seems to not be finding anything, telling me, unexpected element (uri:"", local:"rss").